# How to Spin up docker container & run some command via golang script?

Tags: docker, go

I am planning to automate spinning up container and run some commands on it.
But I get the below error

```
docker run -it alpine sh ls
```

Error I get is

```
docker error : the input device is not a TTY.
```

So I removed interactive part and ran

```
docker run -t alpine sh ls
```

I don't get the shell but docker is spinning

I run above docker commands in golangs **os.exec** package.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
)
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        cmd := exec.Command("docker", "run","-it","alpine","sh","ls")
        cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
        cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
        cmd.Run()
        // log.Println(cmd.Run())
    }()
}()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

My intention is to run multiple shell scripts after spinning up the docker.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the actual code you're using that uses `os.exec`? What is in `MY_CONTAINER`? These commands alone are not very helpful.

Comment: @tentative added the code and image name

Comment: Note that running `sh ls` doesn't make any sense; that's going to result in an error (`sh: can't open 'ls': No such file or directory`). You would want either `sh -c ls` or simply `ls`.

Comment: @larsks 'ls' is just for example. I added there

Comment: A Docker container is a wrapper around some single process.  Does this workflow actually make sense if you substitute "process" for "container"; "start a process, get a shell inside it, and run some commands"?  Also look at the [Docker Go SDK](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/client), and remember that if you can start a container, you can very easily use that ability to root the entire host.

Answer (score 2):

One avenue to explore is the official packages [`moby/moby` `integration-cli`](https://github.com/moby/moby/tree/a586d536be66ea1c5bc9e6ccccb3dbf2eed1f251/integration-cli) and [`moby/moby` `integration-cli/cli` with `cli.go`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/a586d536be66ea1c5bc9e6ccccb3dbf2eed1f251/integration-cli/cli/cli.go).

The [`func Docker(cmd icmd.Cmd, cmdOperators ...CmdOperator) *icmd`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/a586d536be66ea1c5bc9e6ccccb3dbf2eed1f251/integration-cli/docker_cli_run_test.go#L2749) is made to run a `docker` command, with parameters.

[Example, for `docker run`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/a586d536be66ea1c5bc9e6ccccb3dbf2eed1f251/integration-cli/docker_cli_run_test.go#L2749):

```
cli.Docker(cli.Args("run", "--name", name, "--rm", "busybox", "sh", "-c", "sleep 30; echo hi"))
```